# How to get the contents of the documents in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, listdata.svc

I need to get the contents of the documents (.doc/.pdf) using rest api (Postman tool) which belongs to a sharepoint site. How to get the document contents?

Comment: Have you tried by creating custom a web method?

Answer (score 0):

The REST endpoint you want is:

```
/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('<url>')/$value?binaryStringResponseBody=true
```

And here is an example that retrieves the file contents as an `ArrayBuffer` using JavaScript:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
    "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/csrdemos/Pictures/Poipu_Hawaii.jpg')/$value?" +
    "binaryStringResponseBody=true";

// create the xhr
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);

// set response type
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

// callback for when array buffer is ready
xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        // response is ArrayBuffer with the file contents
        console.log(xhr.response);
    }
})

// send the request
xhr.send();
```

**Edit**

I believe my answer will work for SP 2013+, but not sure about that endpoint for 2010. The confusing thing is, your question says 'in SharePoint 2010' but you tagged it `sharepoint-online`?

Anyway, you don't need to use the endpoint, you should be able to put in the url to the file directly, so if you change the url in the above code to:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Pictures/Poipu_Hawaii.jpg?" +
    "binaryStringResponseBody=true";
```

that should work too (even on 2010, though I do not have a 2010 machine handy to test it on).

Comment: This does'nt work in my case. Since it is SP-2010 to get other metadata used ListData.svc. The URL am using to get other metadata is ( <webUrl> + _vti_bin/ListData.svc/ + <CollectionName>). Still am unable to get the page and document contents .

Comment: I have used the second method (in my edit) on 2010 without any problems (i.e. just put in the full path to the file in the URL). BTW, 'doesn't work' isn't very descriptive. You must be getting some kind of error, knowing what it is might help? ;)

Comment: Getting 400 Bad request along with the message "The request URI is not valid. Since the segment 'Pages' refers to a collection, this must be the last segment in the request URI. All intermediate segments must refer to a single resource." in postman tool.